# Captcha stopped working after php hide extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, captcha

I'm using the following code to hide my .php extensions in my .htaccess file.....

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

      # Unless directory, remove trailing slash
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

      # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
      RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

      # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
      RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
      </IfModule>
```

However My Captcha stopped working. The image is being called by the following line of code...

```
     <img src="assets/phpscripts/captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>
```

I tried removing the .php from the image link but still no joy. Any idea on how to sort this?

Comment: What happend if you goto `http://[...]/assets/phpscripts/captcha_code_file?rand=45616846` directly in browser?

Comment: Try `[QSA,L]` instead of `[L]`. So you won't lose `GET` parameters.

Comment: @JoDev it actually gave me a 404 error.

Comment: @PLB Thanks, but I tried that change but it didn't fix it.

Comment: With or wihout ".php" near `captcha_code_file`? Or both? Otherwise, add a rule only for this url...

Comment: Without the .php it gave me the 404 error. With the .php it redirected me to that iana.org/domains/example url. I added this rule as you suggested, above the RewriteCond's and it sorted out, thanks... RewriteRule ^/?assets/phpscripts/captcha_code_file.php$ - [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is to add a rule in the htaccess, for the captcha url.

```
RewriteRule ^/?assets/phpscripts/captcha_code_file.php$ - [L]
```